# Bower - enogit git is not installed or not in the PATH

Tags: git, jenkins, bower

I get following error when my Jenkins build runs:

```
"ENOGIT git is not installed or not in the PATH"
```

However there is no error when I run it from cmd.

The key difference is that one of bower packages uses `git://` protocol instead of `https://` like other packages do.
I tried to override it in git config to use `http://` instead of `git://` but no luck, Git is also in a `PATH`.

Any ideas how to make it work, one of the solutions would be to make bower download package using `https://` not the `git://` is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is not related to protocol. For some reason or another, git executable is not found in the path for your jenkins job. This is different from your user path and system path, so even if it is in those, it seems it is not in jenkins job path.

You can confirm this by running a shell script as a build step and trying to use git there.

You can also try echoing/setting the path before you call bower to troubleshoot/work around the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After some echos I found out that user under which Jenkins runs has no GIT in the path (system user) since I couldn't find a way to log in under this user and edit PATH variable I rebooted server and it started to work as I expected.

Comment: this is pretty much what I said :) it's not related to protocol, your jenkins job didn't have git in its path.

Comment: @eis Yeah, it was quite confusing because usually you can just close cmd and expect path variable to update when you reopen it. The root issue why I couldn't figure it out so quick is that Jenkins runs as system itself not specific user, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You should check PATH in environment variables.
And if path has not location of git... then paste this into PATH :

```
C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
```

And restart gitbash,cmd or jenkin build cmd.